# In App Billing foreground

Tags: android, eclipse

I have inAppBilling working but i'm trying to refine it a little bit. I noticed that when I try in app billing in Angry Birds it opens directly on top of the application but my application pulls in app billing to the foreground/desktop. I read the docs and it states that singleTop must be off and reflection must be used as well with an activity context given and NOT an application context. I have verified that I have all of those things done but its still pulling to the foreground. Any ideas?

My verification:
I have an activity called MyActivity

`Log.d("TEST", mContext.getClass().getName());`

responds back with MyActivity

and in Android Manifest for MyActivity

`android:launchMode="standard"`

EDIT:

The code that starts the checkout activity

```
   void startBuyPageActivity(PendingIntent pendingIntent, Intent intent) {
    if (mStartIntentSender != null) {
        // This is on Android 2.0 and beyond.  The in-app buy page activity
        // must be on the activity stack of the application.
        try {
            // This implements the method call:
            // mActivity.startIntentSender(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
            //     intent, 0, 0, 0);
            mStartIntentSenderArgs[0] = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
            mStartIntentSenderArgs[1] = intent;
            mStartIntentSenderArgs[2] = Integer.valueOf(0);
            mStartIntentSenderArgs[3] = Integer.valueOf(0);
            mStartIntentSenderArgs[4] = Integer.valueOf(0);
            mStartIntentSender.invoke(mActivity, mStartIntentSenderArgs);
            Log.d("TAG", mActivity.getClass().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error starting activity", e);
        }
    } else {
        // This is on Android version 1.6. The in-app buy page activity must be on its
        // own separate activity stack instead of on the activity stack of
        // the application.
        try {
            pendingIntent.send(mActivity, 0 /* code */, intent);
        } catch (CanceledException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error starting activity", e);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is for the in app billing prompt whether it finishes the transaction or cancels to resume back to my game instead of simply closing and finishing. A current fix I have is to start the games Activity again which would result in reloading everything and putting the player back at the main menu page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you mean you're starting a new `Activity` which is switching away from the previous `Activity` then try using `android:style/Theme.Dialog` for the "In App Billing" `Activity`.

Comment: I'm trying to get In App Billing activity to run on my Applications stack and not on its own stack. I don't think `android:style/Theme.Dialog` will help. The sample application for in app billing accomplishes this and it doesn't include that anywhere. I have implemented the sample application into my application so it should be similar but something is occuring

Comment: Unless you show code that demonstrates how you're trying to do this then nobody can help you. Your question is still unclear and, for example, I'm not going to install Angry Birds just to work out what you mean by **"...in Angry Birds it opens directly on top of the application...**

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it can clarify what I want accomplished

Comment: If you've built the In App Billing sample app separately, then it is always going to open as a separate app. It seems to me the "Angry Birds" team simply extracted the code and incorporated it into their own app. That's all I can think of.

Comment: Its not built separately. I incorporated the sample into my application.

Comment: Then in that case, try the `android:style/Theme.Dialog` that I suggested. Just because the sample application code doesn't have that in it doesn't mean the Angry Birds team didn't use it.